# ASUS AX56 USB Wi-Fi adapter(rtl8852au) on raspberry pi 4B/ kernal problem

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, wifi, driver, kernel-module

I'm trying to get my new USB Wifi adapter asus AX56 on my raspberry pi 4B, and the chip of AX56 is RTL8852AU. And I followed this tutorial https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8852au
then it show this problem at make process

```
/rtl8852au $ make
#rm -f .symvers.8852au
make ARCH=aarch64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/build M=/home/ailab4/rtl8852au  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:636: modules] Error 2
```

sudo make install

```
~/rtl8852au $sudo make install
install -p -m 644 8852au.ko  /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89/
install: cannot stat '8852au.ko': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:646: install] Error 1
```

so I use **uname -r** and **uname -a** to check my kernel version

```
/rtl8852au $ uname -a
Linux ailab4 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

```
 $ uname -r
6.1.21-v8+
```

and i also use **~/rtl8852au $ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`** and show:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-6.1.21-v8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-6.1.21-v8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-6.1.21-v8'
```

I had change the newer version of kernel but it still cannot work. Does anyone know what I'm missing, or what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Try by doing:

```
make ARCH=arm64
```

instead of make alone

Comment: I had tried, but it still show the same problem